When I try to use stripe in test mode to buy something it says error internet
I have this issue with my flutter app , I am doing the ui where user can buy a subscription or promotion for homepage/category and when I try my user to buy something I receive this error :
    Detailed error: ClientException with SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = localhost, port = 57616, uri=http://localhost:4000/create-payment-intent
flutter: Stack trace: #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:154:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32)
<asynchronous suspension>

and I don't know what is wrong , here is my server.js file :
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Logging middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
    console.log("Body:", req.body);
    next();
});

// Test route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ status: "Server is running" });
});

// Payment Intent route
app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { amount, currency } = req.body;
        console.log("Creating payment intent:", { amount, currency });

        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: Math.round(parseFloat(amount) * 100),
            currency: currency || "ron"
        });

        console.log("Payment intent created:", paymentIntent.id);
        res.json({ clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});

const PORT = 4000;

// Start server
const server = app.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("Server error:", err);
});


Did u try and change localhost with local ip address.
